# Alternatives for developing UI for MATLAB GUI applications?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to develop a MATLAB application, but MATLAB's UI is not as flexible or as beautiful as some others, like XAML for WPF.  Is it possible to use something else to develop UIs rather than what is provided by MATLAB?

Comment: Take a look at [GUI Layout Toolbox](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47982-gui-layout-toolbox). I've had a lot of success using it to create much more complex and flexible GUIs than is otherwise possible with MATLAB.

Comment: looks great thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use [Matlab Compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler.html) to compile your code to an executable and you can  excute it anywhere you want, e.g. from an interface developed by XAML or WPF.
2. You can use [Matlab Coder](https://it.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html) to generate C or C++ code that you can integrate with your application in your own development environment (e.g., Visual Studio).

The advantage of using the second method over the first is that the result will be native (you can compile to anything you want) and you will be able to modify the code and have one code base. The disadvantage is that you will have to deal with the computer generated code.

P.s. You might want to consider the relatively new [Matlab App Designer](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/app-designer.html) as opposed to the old GUIDE. It is much better. That being said, it is not as good as XAML or WPF.

Comment: thanks, comparing to the XAML in WPF, App designer is not so much sophisticated;)